# Cannot use a referenced XML schema file (xsd) in a C# project

Tags: c#, xml, xsd, getelementbyid

I defined a very simple XML schema, called `MySchema`, which I added to the references of my project:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema id="MySchema"
    elementFormDefault="qualified"
    attributeFormDefault="unqualified"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <xs:element name="UserList">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="User" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:ID" use="required"/>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

On which I should be able to use `XmlDocument.GetElementById`.

My sample XML file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><UserList id="local"/>
```

However, when I run `GetElementById("local")` I still get a "NullReferenceException".

I guess I need to do something more than just adding the xsd file to the reference. Can somebody tell me where I'm going wrong please?

Comment: how are you getting an instance of XmlDocument?

Comment: @Maslow `XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();` I'm not too sure how to use the constructor that needs `XmlNameTable`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like [`XmlDocument.GetElementById`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.getelementbyid%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) doesn't support ID attributes defined in XSD schemas, only DTDs:

> The DOM implementation must have information which defines which attributes are of type ID. Although attributes of type ID can be defined in either XSD schemas or DTDs, this version of the product only supports those defined in DTDs. Attributes with the name "ID" are not of type ID unless so defined in the DTD. Implementations where it is unknown whether the attributes are of type ID are expected to return null.

You can use `SelectSingleNode` with traditional XPath, however:

```
doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("//UserList[@id='local']")
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Too bad ID as an attribute defined in an XSD schema is not supported, though.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't define a DTD or XSD to define what `id` is then the `GetElementById` method does not work.

If you are defining an XSD or DTD in the code you don't show, then update your question.

The DOM implementation must have information which defines which attributes are of type ID. Although attributes of type ID can be defined in either XSD schemas or DTDs, this version of the product only supports those defined in DTDs. Attributes with the name "ID" are not of type ID unless so defined in the DTD. Implementations where it is unknown whether the attributes are of type ID are expected to return Nothing.

http://www.xtremevbtalk.com/showthread.php?t=313101

Based on the XSD at the top of the post, I'd say you aren't loading the xsd into the XmlDocument instance so that it knows which is the `xs:id`

Comment: I hoped that `<xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:ID" use="required"/>` did the trick. Definitely overlooked the bit of information you posted. And yes, I'm not explicitly loading the XSD in the XmlDocument - I thought that simply adding the file to the references was enough.